# Adjusting y-lim Scale in the Plot (matplotlib, pandas) to Achieve Same Scale for Both Plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

```
   AgeGroups Factor Cancer  Frequency
0      00-05      B    Yes        223
1      00-05      A     No        108
2      00-05      A    Yes          0
3      00-05      B     No       6575
4      11-15      B    Yes        143
5      11-15      A     No          5
6      11-15      A    Yes          1
7      11-15      B     No       3669
8      16-20      B    Yes        395
9      16-20      A     No         28
10     16-20      A    Yes          1
11     16-20      B     No       6174
12     21-25      B    Yes        624
13     21-25      A     No         80
14     21-25      A    Yes          2
15     21-25      B     No       8173
16     26-30      B    Yes        968
17     26-30      A     No        110
18     26-30      A    Yes          2
19     26-30      B     No       9143
20     31-35      B    Yes       1225
21     31-35      A     No        171
22     31-35      A    Yes          5
23     31-35      B     No       9046
24     36-40      B    Yes       1475
25     36-40      A     No        338
26     36-40      A    Yes         21
27     36-40      B     No       8883
28     41-45      B    Yes       2533
29     41-45      A     No        782
..       ...    ...    ...        ...
54     71-75      A    Yes       2441
55     71-75      B     No      15992
56     76-80      B    Yes       4614
57     76-80      A     No       5634
58     76-80      A    Yes       1525
59     76-80      B     No      10531
60     81-85      B    Yes       1869
61     81-85      A     No       2893
62     81-85      A    Yes        702
63     81-85      B     No       5692
64     86-90      B    Yes        699
65     86-90      A     No       1398
66     86-90      A    Yes        239
67     86-90      B     No       3081
68     91-95      B    Yes        157
69     91-95      A     No        350
70     91-95      A    Yes         47
71     91-95      B     No       1107
72    96-100      B    Yes         31
73    96-100      A     No         35
74    96-100      A    Yes          2
75    96-100      B     No        230
76      >100      B    Yes          5
77      >100      A     No          1
78      >100      A    Yes          1
79      >100      B     No         30
80     06-10      B    Yes        112
81     06-10      A     No          6
82     06-10      A    Yes          0
83     06-10      B     No       2191
```

with the code:

```
by_factor = counts.groupby(level='Factor')


    k = by_factor.ngroups

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, k, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize=(15, 8))
    for i, (gname, grp) in enumerate(by_factor):
        grp.xs(gname, level='Factor').plot.bar(
            stacked=True, rot=45, ax=axes[i], title=gname)

    fig.tight_layout()
```

I got a beautiful chart, which seems like this:
[image]
This actually served what I was looking for until I realized I wanted to re-adjust my y-axis in such a way that I could have same scale for y-axis in both of the charts. If you look at the right chart 'B', the y-axis has scale of 25000 and chart 'A' has the scale of 10000. Can anyone suggest what would be the best possible approach to have same scale on both charts?. 
I tried:

```
plt.ylim([0,25000])
```

which did rather nothing or didn't change anything in chart 'A'  because this bascially only changes y-axis of chart 'B'.

I would highly appreciate any suggestion to achieve same scale for both plots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the same axis limits for all subplots in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006971/setting-the-same-axis-limits-for-all-subplots-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may of course simply call `.set_ylim()` on the respective axes.  The drawback of this is that you would need to know the limits to set by doing so.
The following solutions do not have this requirement:

#### sharey

In your code you explicitely set `sharey=False`. If you change it to `True`, you get a shared yaxis. You can then use `plt.ylim([0,25000])` to limit the axes, but you don't have to, since they are shared and will adjust automatically.

Minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax.plot([1,3,2])
ax2.plot([2,3,1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

As can be seen the ticklabels of the shared axes are hidden, which might be desirable in many cases.

#### join shared axes

Having two axes, you can make them sharing the same scale using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=False)
ax.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, ax2)

ax.plot([1,3,2])
ax2.plot([2,3,1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Here the ticklabels stay visible. If you don't want that you can turn them off via `ax2.set_yticklabels([])`.

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest  .. Thank you so much.. I just realized sharey = True would have solved my axes problem :)

Comment: It still can solve your problem, you just have to use it ;-)

Comment: It did ! Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Set `ylim` min and max values for every axis in a cycle:

```
for ax in axes: ax.set_ylim([0,25000])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `plt.ylim()` will only adjust the axes for the last figure that was plotted. In order to change the y limits for a specific plot you need to use `ax.set_ylim()`.

So in your case it would be

```
axes[0].set_ylim(0,25000)
axes[1].set_ylim(0,25000)
```

Comment: Thank you Serenity and DavidG.. both worked and served what I was looking for. :)